# Make width proportional to height in css

Tags: html, css

I have the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eob6fty/6/) that has text that could be any length on one side and then I have a box on the other side. Because the text can be any length, the height of `.container` is unknown.

I am trying to figure out how to make the `.box-container` always a square if the height is always 100% of the `.container`.

I know the `padding-bottom:100%` trick but that is only if you know the width and it doesn't matter what the height is. I don't know the width (nor do I care what it is), but I do know the height is going to be 100% of the container. I just need to somehow adjust the width to always be the width of the height of the box and then adjust the `.text-container` so it doesn't overlap.

### In short: I need `.box-container` to *ALWAYS* be a square ratio but also *ALWAYS* have 100% height of `.container`

I hope that makes sense. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="text-container">
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box-container">

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.container { border-radius:3px;box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.25);position:relative; }

.text-container { overflow:hidden;padding:25px;width:70% }

.box-container { position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:30%;height:100%;background-color:#F9F9F9;padding:20px;}
```

Comment: Not possible without JS, unfortunately AFAIK.

Comment: What if `.container`'s height is >= its width?

Comment: possible duplcate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041691/inner-div-with-square-ratio-and-flexbox/51041869#51041869

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with only css! Use this jQuery code:

```
var boxContainerH = $('.box-container').height();
$('.box-container').width(boxContainerH);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4eob6fty/51/