# CSS - Aspect Ratio and 100% viewport height

Tags: css

I am trying to set the aspect ratio of a div to portrait (9:16) like this..

```css
.ratio {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: teal;
  padding-bottom: 177.77%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  16:9
</div>
```

This is working as expected, but I am now wanting to make it so that it has a maximum height of 100% of the viewport.

I am trying to make sure it fits exactly onto the screen whilst keeping the aspect ratio and not introducing scrollbars.

What's my best approach?

Comment: see here:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_aspect_ratio_169

Comment: That's the same as my example, I am trying to set a maximum height

Comment: do you mean:`max-height: 100vh;`?

Comment: Have already tried max-height but it has made no difference

Comment: I think min not max if I understand you well

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/24yezLkp/4/

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: I don't want scrollbars. I want to maximum height to be 100% of the viewport. This is for a fixed layout

Comment: in your .ratio class, add `height: 100vh;padding-right: 56%; width:0` and remove the padding bottom, it this what you wanted?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041691/inner-div-with-square-ratio-and-flexbox/51041869#51041869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the ratio of `16/9 = 1.778` to calculate the width using `calc()` css function

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.ratio {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: teal;
  width: calc(1.778 * 100vh);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  16:9
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend then using the `vh` unit for the height then.

```
height: 100vh;
```