# Keep div centered with keeping aspect ratio and resizing vertically or horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can find multiple half solutions, but I am looking for a complete solution to my issue. I have a div that I would like to be centered in the screen with a fixed aspect ratio, that div should in essence always be completely visible, so that div is always the largest it can be whilst keeping the aspect ratio. regardless of resizing the window vertically and horizontally.

There is a codepen here: https://codepen.io/william-bang/pen/ZjyWRd

That I created, this only solves the issue horizontally but not vertically. I have managed to get it working with and  but sizing behaves differently for that. I am looking for a CSS solution, although I am open to a JS solution, if anyone is absolutely sure that no solution exists.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto
}

.img {
  padding-top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="img">
    **IMG HERE**
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions, this has had me stumped for many hours. thanks in advance :)

Update, the div needs to maintain its aspect ratio on a varying page and at all times be its own maximum size.

@Grenther Thanks for your response, I tried modifying the answer you gave to do it purely in CSS and not having to use a CSS preprocessor. That went really well, until I realized that CSS media queries does not support standard CSS variables, otherwise the method you proposed would have been possible without SCSS but perhaps you already knew that.

```css
:root {
  --ogW: 1600;
  --ogH: 900;
  --ratio: calc( var(--ogW) / var(--ogH));
}

 body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ratio {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 177vh) {
    width: 90vw; 
    height: calc( 90vw / var(--ratio)); 
  } 

  @media screen and (min-width: 177vh) {
    width: calc( 90vh * var(--ratio));  
    height: 90vh;
  }

}

.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">

  <div class="div">
    
    Hello!
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041869/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif The problems are different, this problem aims to keep the aspect ratio of a div when the width & height of the window is changing. The other one is trying to keep a ratio between the container and the box. That is not the aim here.

Comment: simply replace the container by the window and read again your sentence ;) .. by the way I simply tagged as *possible duplicate*, I didn't close as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final Update:**

It turned into a SCSS question, with any input for variable width or height it can be done like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/832v5f0L/41

```
 $div-width : 1600;
 $div-height : 900;

 $ratio: $div-width / $div-height;

  @media screen and (max-width: (100 * $ratio) + vh) {
    width: 100vw; // always 100vw to fill
    height: (100 / $ratio) + vw; // 100 / ratio
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: (100 * $ratio) + vh) {
    width: (100 * $ratio) + vh;  //100 * ratio
    height: 100vh; // always 100vh to fill
  }
```

Updated answer:

Media query portrait automatically activates when width is smaller than height. Which makes sure we can use the vh and vw to obtain the maximum possible size without reaching an overflow.

The ratio between the width and height will make sure you can get a fixed aspect ratio.

```css
    body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* 
100vh * (100 / height) 
with hright 50:
100vh * 100 / 50 = 200vh
*/

@media screen and (max-width: 200vh) {
  .wrapper {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 50vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200vh) {
  .wrapper {
      width: 200vh;
      height: 100vh;
  }
}

.img {
/*   padding-top: 50%; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  background-img: url()
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="img">
    **IMG HERE**
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Update:
min - max width queries

Comment: This is the effect I already have. In the example you gave the div.img will only resize when scaled horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang I've updated the answer. Hopefully this will achieve what you're after ;)

Comment: Hey, this is a really cool trick, and thanks for writing back :) This, however, limits the maximum size the div can achieve. So if the div was very wide it wouldn't stretch to it's full size.

Comment: What do you mean? if you set width: 100vw/vh it's the width of the full page. Let's say you have a 2:1 aspect ratio and you want it to span the full width no matter what, whilst being fully visible in your viewport. You'd do `width:100vh; height:50vh;` and in portrait `width:100vw; height:50vw;`. I mean unless you want it to allow to be bigger than the viewport.

Comment: I've tried doing that here: https://codepen.io/william-bang/pen/ZjyWRd, but the box does not stretch fully. Because the width in landscape orientation is limited by the vertical height of the window (vh).

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang I've made another edit, you have to calculate it depending on the width and height but it should be usable.

Comment: I have to hand it to you @Grenther, this is aweomse. I've used your code and i've set a max width of 400 and height 200 and it works perfectly. But I don't understand the math with the vh. So when I change my div ratio, it goes bad. I've created a fiddle, can you please use my sass vars and weave it into you vh code using math, so i can see how you've worked the vh sizes? https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/832v5f0L/

Comment: @Grenther Thanks for your response, I tried modifying the answer you gave to do it purely in CSS and not having to use a CSS preprocessor. That went really well until I realized that CSS media queries do not support standard CSS variables, otherwise the method you proposed would have been possible without SCSS but perhaps you already knew that. You can se my updated post.

Comment: Yeah, css variables have some limits. "The var() function can be used in place of any part of a value in any property on an element. The var() function can not be used as property names, selectors, or anything else besides property values. (Doing so usually produces invalid syntax, or else a value whose meaning has no connection to the variable.)" I'd suggest marking it as answered and call it a day @WilliamLarsenBang

Answer (score 1):

See the below code snippet. As you adjust the wrapper width, the `img` will scale to fit while maintaining it's aspect ratio

The `img` will also be vertically centered and horizontally within the `.wrapper` element

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding:20px 40px;
  background:grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/01/29/00/47/search-engine-76519_960_720.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have achieved the effect with an img tag, but I am looking for a div solution only. If there was some way of parenting a div underneath a img that would be great, but this does not solve my issue. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang I've edited the example using a `transform` property. Not personally a fan of using it, but the updated example should solve your issues with css

Comment: Note: this only applies when the div has children. Otherwise it has nothing to scale it's width to

Comment: Sorry, I did not try out the code properly I did not know there was a method of Height called "fit-content" That is pretty ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, I've been trying for ages to solve but getting it to resize on a vertical height with out using flex was proving a hard task.

But [@Grenther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995187/grenther) answer seems to actually work without using an image. His 1x2 ratio div stays true when adjusting the window width and height.

I then modified his code so that there is a `max-height` and `max-width` on the div. I could only get this to work with his `200px x 400px` ratio.

It would be awesome if [@Grenther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995187/grenther) could update my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jndmoz6v/) code so what ever div size/ratio variable is set, his clever `vh` method sizes would adjust using `sass math` so that any set div size would work. Even I'm struggling to see how his version works. But if the math is in the sass code for each `vh` dimension, we might be able to understand his wizardry.

[@Grenther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995187/grenther) version here: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/jndmoz6v/

```
 /* div size vars and div ratio3 */
 $div-width : 400;
 $div-height : 200;

 body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ratio {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* set your div max-size here  */
  max-width: $div-width + px;
  max-height: $div-height + px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 200vh) {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vw;

  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 200vh) {
    width: 200vh;
    height: 100vh;

  }

}

.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;

}
```

I know this is not sass question, but i'm just using this so we can see [@Grenther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995187/grenther)'s answer logic.

---

I tried the math myself but when I change the div sizes/ratio it does not work like his version.

See my fail: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/Lkebpyws/

```
$div-width : 400;
$div-height : 200;

.ratio {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* set your div max-size here  */
  max-width: $div-width + px;
  max-height: $div-height + px;

  @media screen and (max-width: $div-height + 'vh') {
    width: ($div-width / 4) + vw;
    height: ($div-height / 4) + vw;

  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $div-height + 'vh') {
    width: ($div-width / 2) + vh;
    height: ($div-height / 2) + vh;

  }

}

...
```

Comment: My final update should provide a sufficient solution, please see my updated answer. (I did leave the max-height and max-width commented, but it works well even if you don't)